# Installing GRUB onto a USB stick (Server 20.04)

Tags: server, grub2, system-installation, 20.04

I'm installing Ubuntu Server 20.04 on a HPE MicroServer Gen8. Due to its BIOS restrictions, it can only boot up from a HDD in bay 1 when not using the hardware RAID (not compatible with Linux). I have an SSD where the OS would be installed, but according to [this](https://blog.linuxserver.io/2015/03/24/setting-up-a-linux-home-server-using-the-hp-proliant-microserver-gen8-g1610t-3/) guide, I need to install GRUB onto a USB stick because of the aforementioned limitation.

I breeze through the installation, expecting to see the "Device for boot loader installation" option. There's none. So my question is; where do I find the option to install GRUB on the USB stick? Or is it even needed? I may very well be blind and/or stupid having missed something completely obvious.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you can boot the computer in BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode), and if you want an amd64 image for 64-bit PC architecture, I think you might have better luck with the Ubuntu **`mini.iso`** and the old style Debian installer, that the Ubuntu developers consider deprecated, but many users (including me) consider much more flexible than the current 'Ubuntu Live Server' with the Curtin installer.

  'Focal' is the name of the developing release that was released as 20.04 LTS. So

  - [this link (with the **`mini.iso`**)](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot) and
  - [this link (with checksums)](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/)

  should provide what you need.
- Otherwise you might step back to [Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/bionic/), which will be supported at least until April 2023 (Select the **Ubuntu Server** with the old style Debian installer, in contrast to 'Ubuntu Live Server' with the Curtin installer).

Comment: Thanks, got it to install with the mini.iso. The problem now is that it doesn't want to boot. I have GRUB in the USB stick and the rest in the SSD but it still won't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the computer fail to boot completely, or does it boot to grub, but then fails to make the Ubuntu Server to run? How did you boot the computer from the mini.iso? Is there a way to control the boot order, which drive the computer tries to boot from?

Comment: Some HP computers do not want to boot via grub and USB with GPT, but it works, when you change to the old MSDOS (legacy) partition table.

Comment: When I choose "boot from USB" in the boot menu, it simply skips it and goes straight to the last one in the list (boot from Ethernet). Could always try to install GRUB along with Ubuntu to the SSD to see if it works.

Comment: https://www.admfactory.com/hp-microserver-gen8-boot-from-ssd-install-on-odd-bay/ Got it working using this guide. Didn't think to check the RAID controller. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @chefz, I'm glad you have a working system now :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of doing the same with my gen8 (currently running 18.04 with OS installed on SSD in bay 1 which will be moved to ODD SATA to allow another mechanical drive in bay1)

I have not yet tested on the actual machine but had success in a VM setup with two drives (simulating the ODD SATA and the USB/SD Card)

Steps to replicate:
Once you are at the storage configuration you chose; (x) Custom storage layout.

1. You tell the installer to use the USB/SD card as boot drive (it will create a small partition on that drive)
2. You add a second partition to the same drive where you set the /boot mount point
3. / should be set on the larger drive connected to the ODD SATA port.

See screen with the partition layout.
[Ubuntu 20.04 Live Server installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBSqX.png)